# HTML mobile friendly website

Tags: jquery, html, css, mobile, mobile-website

I have created a simple website and I am trying to make it mobile friendly.

I have tried using various methods such as:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px) and (max-width: 900px)' href='mobile.css' />
```

And jQuery:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css" />
<link id="size-stylesheet" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>   
function adjustStyle(width) {
width = parseInt(width);
if (width < 900) {
$("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "mobile.css");
}  else {
   $("#size-stylesheet").attr("href", "main.css"); 
 }
}

$(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
$(window).resize(function() {
 adjustStyle($(this).width());
});
});
</script>
```

No method seems to work. For example, on a mobile device the webpage looks the same (from `main.css` and not `mobile.css`). Any ideas or any other way to do it?

EDIT:

I now have the following set up:

```
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)' href='main.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='mobile.css' />
```

But on a mobile device it uses main.css (which it should not do as the minimum width isn't 901px). If I switch the css files around, for example main.css going to min-width 10px and max-width 900px, and mobile.css going to min-width 901px. Then the website changes accordingly, and on a computer the mobile css is now shown (which should happen), but the mobile device is also showing the mobile css (which it shouldn't because they have been swapped around). So the mobile device is constantly using the incorrect css.

EDIT EDIT:

Viewport kind of makes it work. But there is some issue, for example I update my CSS file. I check mobiletest.me and the changes are made, but on a physical mobile device (the same device on mobiletest.me) the changes are made

Comment: You may want to read up on media queries, especially since they don't require Javascript to work properly.

Comment: Yeah I know. I have tried two different ways, media queries and Javascript. Neither are working. I don't know why it isn't making a difference

Comment: @Thomas I think for mobile device you may need to reduce `min-width`?

Comment: To what size? For any iPhone really

Comment: @Thomas Somewhere in the the 300's basically.

Comment: Media queries will only work if you've set the viewport meta tag. See https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/layouts/rwd-fundamentals/set-the-viewport for a decent explanation.

Comment: @thomas  you'd prob should start using inspect element on the elements you want to check, one possible simple reason the methods below are not working is due to higher specifity in previous rules e.g  `.parent .child{}` we can't really tell based on the information given

Comment: Thats not true. I have other sites that do not have a viewport meta tag, but just have the first example I gave and they work fine.

Comment: @David I don't think that has anything to do with it. Its the fact that no matter what width I give, the mobile device uses the CSS which is it not suppose to do. Check my UPDATE please

Comment: @thomas what im saying is we dont have the information to solve this for you. There is a website called mobiletest.me where you can test in the different phone sizes (or chrome has a extention) and it gives you the dimesions below (css size) . but iphone is around 450 px dependant on version so your 701px is too high. You would be best to just set the max width and use media queries to refine. Btw viewport is pretty much required for a lot of phone browsers, definitely in chrome on my xperia, not too sure about iphone.

Comment: What I'm going to say is this is all over the place and so are the answers. This whole area covers a lot of bases and learning to create a mobile site in an answer on SO is overly broad and just not going to happen. @Thomas you are going to have to sit back and do some studying of the multitude of online articles and tutorials to get a grasp of the basics cause everyone is just throwing spaghetti against the wall to see what sticks.

Comment: @Rob I know the basics. I know how to do it. I'm just saying there may be some error because the code isn't working or it doesn't update as it should.

Comment: @David The weird thing is that on mobiletest.me the webpage comes out how it should, but on a physical mobile device it doesn't

Comment: How about recognizing mobile browser and than link to mobile style sheet or normal stylesheet?

Comment: @Evochrome Yeah thats what I'm trying to do by using:                            <link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (min-width: 701px)' href='main.css' />
<link rel='stylesheet' media='screen and (max-width: 700px)' href='mobile.css' />

Comment: @thomas you need the viewport statement, mobiletest.me is not really a mobiledevice I have experienced this before where i forgot to add the statement. put `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` within the head tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way you could do it is a CSS3 @media Rule:

```
    @media screen and (max-width: ...px){
   }
```

This allows you to change the your style at certain screen sizes:

for Example:

```css
#div1 {
  width: 60%;
  height: 50px;
  background: red;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  #div1 {
    width: 80%;
    height: 50px;
    background: blue;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="div1"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you I have this working now. I was just wondering can this work in a html file or does it have to be a css file?

Comment: Optimally it should be in a css file, you could use <style> tags to do it in html but I would not suggest it.

Comment: Ok point taken. One last question can this work with the body. For example @media (max-width: 900px){
body {

Comment: Yea if you want all it is doing is saying: "at screen size 900px switch style to  the one listed below" really any element  in you css can be changed using it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this,

```
function adjustStyle(width) 
{
   width = parseInt(width);
   if (width < 900) 
   {
      $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="main.css"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
      $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="mobile.css"]').attr('disabled', 'false');
   }  
   else 
   {
      $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="mobile.css"]').attr('disabled', 'true');
      $('link[rel=stylesheet][href~="main.css"]').attr('disabled', 'false');
   }
 }
```

and disable enable as per your requirement.

Comment: Thank you. What does the disabled/enabled mean by the way? would I need them both enabled for this to work?

Comment: @Thomas did it work? It basically disables the functionality of the included stylesheet.

Comment: Unfortunately not. I tried it with disabled true and then tried it with enabled true. But both didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Viewport meta tag will make you happy. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=Mobile%2FViewport_meta_tag

Comment: Viewport kind of makes it work. But there is some issue, for example I update my CSS file. I check mobiletest.me and the changes are made, but on a physical mobile device (the same device on mobiletest.me) the changes are made

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

And:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   (function(a){(jQuery.browser=jQuery.browser||{}).mobile=/(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|iris|kindle|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|mobile.+firefox|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows ce|xda|xiino/i.test(a)||/1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(a.substr(0,4))})(navigator.userAgent||navigator.vendor||window.opera);


    if(jQuery.browser.mobile)
    {
       void(document.styleSheets.item(1).enabled=true); //2nd item(which should be mobile css)
    }    
    else{
        void(document.styleSheets.item(1).disabled=true);
    }
</script>
```

Detect mobile browsers and enable mobilestylesheet

Hope it works :)

**Note:** `item(1)` is the second stylesheet

Comment: Thank you I will try this, so should this be in a second .js file?

Comment: No that is not even neccesary, I normally just place it inside the head tag

Comment: Thank you. I'm confused as where do I put the CSS in the code? my CSS file is called mobile.css

Comment: I have tried placing my CSS files inside item(main.css) and item(mobile.css), but nothing happens (only main.css is shown)

Comment: Give me a moment, I will try to create an example :)

Comment: I think I know what you're doing wrong, have you added jquery inside your head tags? Anyway, here is the example: http://evoc.cf . Check it first on your desktop and then on your mobile phone :) (phone has a grey background). It doesn't work when you simulate it in chrome or something like that. **Note:** add jquery: `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>` and past the code in the answer between `<script>` and `</script`.(all inside the `head` tags) Hope it solves your problem :)

Comment: Thank you for your help i'll try that. But I dont get where I should put my CSS files. You have item(0) and item(0) and have just one css = <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/1.css" />. So where should I state my mobile.css and main.css? Sorry for the trouble

Comment: @Thomas 1. No problem. 2. you can leave your code like stated(except for the scripts, you can remove those) in your question, just add the code as shown in my answer(I recently fixed an error, so I guess you'll have to recopy the code) :) **EDIT:** Also remove the `media` properties from your link tags

Comment: And last but not least, make sure your `mobile.css` is the second link (and `main.css` the first)

Comment: So like this: if(jQuery.browser.mobile) { void(document.styleSheets.item(main.css).enabled=true); //2nd item(which should be mobile css) } else{ void(document.styleSheets.item(mobile.css).disabled=true); }

Comment: No, the code gets **all** stylesheets within the page. The first stylesheet will be `item(0)`. The second stylesheet(mobile.css) will be `item(1)`. So you can just copy and paste the code from the answer into your HTML. If you give me your HTML code I can also fix it for you if you want :) Also, do you want to disable the `main.css` when `mobile.css` is active?